# Uncaught TypeError: NativePromise.resolve is not a function

Tags: rxjs, angular5

I am using angular 5. I am facing this issue while running application.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JN1J.png)

Comment: polyfills.bundle.js:8228 Uncaught TypeError: NativePromise.resolve is not a function
    at Object.setNativePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:8228)
    at desc.set (polyfills.bundle.js:8622)
    at module.exports (polyfills.bundle.js:465)
    at $export (polyfills.bundle.js:185)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:304215)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:303903)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.bundle.js:142572)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:55)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask